# What is the most efficient approach to interpolate values between two FEM meshes in 2D?

Tags: interpolation, mesh

I am looking for efficient algorithm to interpolate values from one unstructured 2D mesh grid to another. Both grids are constructed using the same type of elements (triangles or quadrilaterals). Both meshes are created for the same geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the recent manuscripts by Caroline Japhet and Martin Gander. They have a few papers in this direction.